# Theme.Holo.Dialog text is unreadable

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Activity containing a single EditText and a Button that uses a custom style, derived from Theme.Holo.Dialog. The Activity is defined as:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".activity.MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/activity_myactivity"
    android:theme="@style/Dialog">
```

The style Dialog is defined as:

```
<style name="Dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
</style>
```

However, when the activity is launched, the text in the EditText is black on a black background, making it unreadable. I can change this in the above style definition by adding `<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>`, but I feel like I must be doing something wrong, as the pre 3.x `Theme.Dialog` seemed to have the text color, etc already defined. (I would use that but am unhappy with the inconsistency with the dialog with the rest of my app that is using the Holo theme)

Answer (score 0):

Update : I tried your code on ICS seems to work fine..

[image]

Comment: Right... but then the whole Dialog is bright white, not black as desired and as Theme.Dialog does.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:setInverseBackgroundForced="true"` on your activity